# check if record exists in database using LINQ

Tags: c#, linq, casting

I am getting a cast error here but I do not understand as to why.

```
protected bool isPlayerdb(string userName)
{
    try
    {
        Users adminUsers = from users in SoccerEntities.Users
                           where users.roleId == new Guid("ED85788D-72DA-4D0A-8D5E-B5378FC00592") 
                           && users.UserName == userName
                           select users;

        if (adminUsers != null)
            return true;
        else
            return false;
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        throw new EntityContextException("isPlayer failed.", ex);
    }
}
```

Error in debugger is:

> Error 11  Cannot implicitly convert type 
>   `'System.Linq.IQueryable<soccerCmsDal.Users>'` to 'soccerCmsDal.Users'. An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?) C:\new code\UniteCms\UniteCms\soccerCmsDal\SocerDataAccess.cs   80  23  soccerCmsDal

Comment: What is the type of `Users` ?

Answer (score 10):

If you need only one record use [FirstOrDefault](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb549141(v=vs.100).aspx) or [SingleOrDefault](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb359429(v=vs.100).aspx):

```
Users adminUsers = (from users in SoccerEntities.Users
                           where users.roleId == new Guid("ED85788D-72DA-4D0A-8D5E-B5378FC00592") && users.UserName == userName
                           select users).FirstOrDefault();
```

If you need to check, if player exists, you can use [Any](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb343630(v=vs.100).aspx):

```
bool exists = (from users in SoccerEntities.Users
                           where users.roleId == new Guid("ED85788D-72DA-4D0A-8D5E-B5378FC00592") && users.UserName == userName
                           select users).Any();
```

Answer (score 3):

You're asking to assign a sequence value to single entity variable. That's like trying to do this:

```
// Won't work for the same reason
string name = new List<string> { "foo", "bar" };
```

If you're just trying to find out whether there are any results, you can use `Any` - and there's an overload of that taking a predicate as an argument, so you don't need a query expression at all.

Additionally, any time you find yourself writing:

```
if (condition)
    return true;
else
    return false;
```

you can just use:

```
if (condition)
```

So we end up with:

```
protected bool isPlayerdb(string userName)
{
    try
    {
        return SoccerEntities
            .Users
            .Any(user => user.roleId == new Guid("ED85788D-72DA-4D0A-8D5E-B5378FC00592") 
                         && user.UserName == userName)
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        throw new EntityContextException("isPlayer failed.", ex);
    }
}
```

Note that:

- Your method name violates .NET naming conventions - consider `PlayerExists` instead
- Catching `Exception` is rarely a good idea, IME - consider catching more specific exceptions
- I've changed the name of the variable used in the predicate from `users` (which was the range variable name in the query expression) to `user`, because the predicate acts on a *single* user. Naming matters for clear code - making it clear whether you're dealing with a *single* entity or *multiple* entities helps readability. (That confusion was what led you to the compile-time failure.)

Comment: this was already answered and ur answers is not the case the above was so no need to repeat

Comment: @kymberly: No idea what "is not the case above" means, but the existing answer does not mention the overload of `Any` which includes the predicate... and using that simplifies the code significantly. See the sample code I've now included.

Comment: @kymberly: Additionally, my answer tries to explain *why* you were getting the error you did, as well as how to fix it.